# Windows AKS - Container lifecycle hooks

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to implment lifecycle hooks with windows AKS. setup deployment.yaml as below as part of helm, but after deployment, pod started successfully but did not run any lifecycle hook events (poststart in this case).. anyone able to implement this correctly.. any syntax errors in below file..

```
containers:
    - name: {{ .Values.deployment.name }}
      image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
      imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
      #{{- if eq (default .Values.env "prod") "stg" }}
      lifecycle:
        preStart:
          exec:
            command:
            - "powershell.exe"
            - "-command"
            - " wget '{{ .Values.config.connectionstringsasurl }}' -OutFile 'c:\\www\\sensei\\web\\ConnectionStrings.config' ; wget '{{ .Values.config.appsettingsasurl }}' -OutFile 'c:\\www\\sensei\\web\\AppSettings.config' ; "
        postStart:
          exec:
            command:
            - powershell.exe
            - -command
            - " wget '{{ .Values.config.connectionstringsasurl }}' -OutFile 'c:\\www\\sensei\\web\\ConnectionStrings.config' ; wget '{{ .Values.config.appsettingsasurl }}' -OutFile 'c:\\www\\sensei\\web\\AppSettings.config' ; "
      #{{- end }}
      ports:
      - containerPort: 85
```

Comment: share logs from the pod?

Comment: `Events:
  Normal  Scheduled  6m58s  default-scheduler         Successfully assigned site-stg/app-site-ffc77bf48-nx5bg to akswnspot000000
  Normal  Pulling    6m55s  kubelet, akswnspot000000  Pulling image "acr.azurecr.io/os:site20200611-15930"
  Normal  Pulled     4m53s  kubelet, akswnspot000000  Successfully pulled image "acr.azurecr.io/os:site20200611-15930"
  Normal  Created    4m53s  kubelet, akswnspot000000  Created container sensei-newsite
  Normal  Started    4m47s  kubelet, akswnspot000000  Started container sensei-newsite`

Comment: No lifecycle hook logs post started container log

Comment: Hello @ReddipalleNagarjun, correct me if i´m wrong but I think there is no preStart kubernetes hook? There is only PostStart and PreStop mentioned in kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/). About postStart hook, could you try to use some simple powershell command to check if it´s problem with wget or whole lifecycle hook?